# Find $f$ if $f''(x) = 3 \sqrt{x}$ if $f(4) = 20$, $f'(4) = 7$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

Find $f$ if $f''(x) = 3 \sqrt{x}$ if $f(4) = 20$, $f'(4) = 7$

$$\int \:\:3 \sqrt{x}\:dx = 2x^{\frac{3}{2}}+C \text{ (1st derivative) }$$
$$\int \:\: 2x^{\frac{3}{2}} dx = \dfrac{4x^\frac{5}{2}}{5} \text{ (original function) }$$

I think I did the integration right, but when I plug in $f(4)$, I get $25.6$, and when I plug in $f'(4)$, I get $16$. However the question says $'if'$ $f(4) = 20$, $f'(4) = 7$

---

Is my math incorrect? Have I made any errors? Because the answer does not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

You have that $$f'(x)-f'(4)=\int_4^x f''(t)dt=\left[2t^{3/2}\right]_4^x=2x^{3/2}-2\cdot4^{3/2}=2x^{3/2}-4\sqrt 2.$$ Since $f'(4)=7$ we have

$$f'(x)=2x^{3/2}+7-4\sqrt 2.$$

Proceed in similar way to get $f(x).$

Comment: We just started indefinite, Im not sure that Im supposed to use definite.

Comment: Have in mind the FTC. That is $F(x)-F(a)=\int_a^x f(t)dt.$ Since you know $F(a)$ and $f$ you can get $F(x).$

Answer (score 0):

A problem like this can be classified into  general diffirential equation or particular diffirential  equation since he gave you 2 conditions this mean it's  particular  DE 
So all you have to do  is to do the first integration  and bring first constant from the condition he gave you then integrate again and bring the second constant from the second condition . You ignored  C and C1 and that's wrong  this is not limited integration

Comment: $$\int \:\:3 \sqrt{x}\:dx = 2x^{\frac{3}{2}}+C_1 \text{ (1st derivative) }$$
$$\int \:\: 2x^{\frac{3}{2}} + C_1 dx = \dfrac{4x^\frac{5}{2}}{5} + C_1x\text{ (original function) }$$

Comment: Is that what you mean?

Comment: Bring C1  from the given condition which is f'(4)=7

Comment: Bring C1  from the given condition which is f'(4)=7 then 7=2*4^3/2+c and get the value of C the integrate again another constant will appear get It from the second condition  do you understand  me?

Comment: Alright so, the $f'(x) = 2x^{\frac{3}{2}} + C_1$, but $f'(4) = 7$, thus $7 = 2(4)^{\frac{3}{2}} +C_1$, giving us $C_1$ equal to $-9$

Comment: Then our original function is $2x^{\frac{3}{2}} - 9x + C_2$

Comment: $f(4) = 20$, so, $20 = 2(4)^{\frac{3}{2}} - 9(4) + C_2$, giving us $C_2 = 40$

Comment: So we actually have $f(x) = 2x^{\frac{3}{2}} -9x + 40$

Comment: Correct  but don't  forget to integrate 2x^3/2 to make it  4/4 x^5/2 then substitute  with the second condition

Comment: So f (4)=20, 20 =4/5 (4)^5/2_9*4+C2 now you have C2   then  write the original function with the values of constants that you brought and it's over

Comment: Why would I integrate $f(x)$?

Comment: You will integrate  f' not f (x)